# How to create segue or new view controller to show on different view controller

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am trying create an app using swift 2, the app will have a user type in a name, after the user adds a clients name I want the user to be able to click on the name and take them to another page where they can see what the cell holds. 
This is what I have but I'm not sure how to create the new segue or view controller. All the name are being stored in CoreData.

View Controller:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var people = [NSManagedObject]()

    @IBAction func addName(sender: AnyObject) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Client",
            message: "Add a new client",
            preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save",
            style: .Default,
            handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) -> Void in
                let textField = alert.textFields!.first
                self.saveName(textField!.text!)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
        })

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",
            style: .Default) { (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        }

        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler {
            (textField: UITextField) -> Void in
        }

        alert.addAction(saveAction)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)

        presentViewController(alert,
            animated: true,
            completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "Clients"
        tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self,
            forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
        numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return people.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell =
        tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")

        let person = people[indexPath.row]

        cell!.textLabel!.text =
            person.valueForKey("name") as? String

        return cell!
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView,didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        // either present the view controller for new page or perform the Segue
        //self.people = self.tableView[indexPath.row]
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func saveName(name: String) {
        //1
        let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

        //2
        let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Person",
            inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

        let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
            insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

        //3
        person.setValue(name, forKey: "name")

        //4
        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            //5
            people.append(person)
        } catch let error as NSError  {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        //1
        let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

        //2
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")

        //3
        do {
            let results =
            try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
            people = results as! [NSManagedObject]
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
```

ViewController2:

```
import Foundation

class ViewController2{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**In your storyboard**

In your `storyboard`you need to drag a relationship between the viewControllers that you want to segue from. In your case from `ViewController` to `ViewController2`. Then select that relationship and go to the "Attributes inspector" and add an identifier.

**In your code**

In your tableView `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` add this line:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("YOUR IDENTIFIER ID", sender: nil)
```

Add this segue function

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!)
    {
        // you can skip this line if you want, but good to have if you have multiple segues
        if (segue.identifier == "YOUR IDENTIFIER ID")
        {
            // create an instance to your second viewController
            let second = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController2

            // now you can access variables and function in ViewController2 by using "second"
        }
    }
```

Then you should be able to to segue when you click on a row in your ViewController to your ViewController2

**In your storyboard**

In your `storyboard`you need to drag a relationship between the viewControllers that you want to segue from. In your case from `ViewController` to `ViewController2`. Then select that relationship and go to the "Attributes inspector" and add an identifier.

**In your code**

In your tableView `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` add this line:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("YOUR IDENTIFIER ID", sender: nil)
```

Add this segue function

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!)
    {
        // you can skip this line if you want, but good to have if you have multiple segues
        if (segue.identifier == "YOUR IDENTIFIER ID")
        {
            // create an instance to your second viewController
            let second = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController2

            // now you can access variables and function in ViewController2 by using "second"
        }
    }
```

Then you should be able to to segue when you click on a row in your ViewController to your ViewController2

**UPDATE**

**Your code example**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView,didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("YOUR IDENTIFIER ID", sender: self.tableView[indexPath.row])
    }

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!)
{
     let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController2
     // secondViewController = name of the instance to ViewController2
     // second = the name of a variable that you have created in ViewController2
    // sender is the value that was passed as a parameter from self.tableView[indexPath.row] in performSegueWithIdentifier. You have to check what this value consists
     secondViewController.second = sender
}
```

If you do it this way it will work.

Comment: when i add a relationship should it just be show or show detail?

Comment: Use "Show". Show(e.g. Push), Show Detail(e.g. Replace).

Comment: in the viewcontroller2 class will there be much needed to write or do i just call the tableview?

Comment: You could assign values from ViewController to ViewController2 as the example shows above and then in your viewDidLoad just call tableView.reloadData() if that is enough for you, hard to say...

Comment: I have this in my viewcontroller2:   import UIKit

class ViewController2:UIViewController{
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var userDisplay: UILabel!
    
    var second = ""
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        userDisplay.text = second
    }
    
    func printMe(){
        print("I am a controller")
    }         
    
  is there something I am missing or should add?

Comment: From ViewController in the prepareForSegue function you could type second.second = "I´m coming from the first controller" and if you want to call your print function you could also type second.printMe()

Comment: I can't get it to move to a different page when i click the names that are being populated.

Comment: I have added a code example that you can use to your code, so just update the code in your class. This is a working example and I can recommend to read some Swift documentation to help you out with the Swift language.